# cakePHP deployment on Azure

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have a cakePHP running on the local machine without problems but when I deploy it on Azure I get this error 'An internal error occured' with no more hints. seriously need help!!

Comment: put the debug mode to 2 and let us know what sort of error. There might problem with server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial might work for you-[setup cakephp on azure](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2012/07/30/how-to-use-cakephp-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)

Comment: it seems I'm getting this error from using the DebugKit. After messing it around a bit I now have this error 'Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default.'

Comment: I now get this error 'Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default.' here is my Post Model                                 <?php
 class Post extends AppModel {
 

  public $validate = array(
   'title' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty'
   ),
   'body' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty'
   )
  ); 
  
  public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
   return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
  } 
  public $belongsTo = array('User');
   
  
 }
?>

Comment: I think you understand what this error said... You are asking to create a table named `posts`. If you already have that table on database, then update your question with your database setting on databases.php.